# How to Run a batch file using PHP

Tags: php, batch-file, execution

I am trying to execute a batch file using php.  I am using the following code:

```
echo exec($batch_exec_string);
```

$batch_exec_string is my batch file that is selected.

However, it will execute but it executes incorrectly.  After execution of a batch file selected the following error occurs in the log file of the batch.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Exception in thread "main"

Comment: please show the command in `batch_exec_string`, and the thing it's trying to run. You're asking about PHP, and showing a Java error: you've not told us enough to help.

Comment: You should also be aware that there are differences between the web server user environment and your own logged in user. I would hazard a guess that this is also part of your problem, if not being wholly related to a JAVA issue

Comment: echo exec('C:\CTBATCH\rp\script\CP_PDF_BATCH.bat');  When this runs it outputs the above java code. I don't know why it does that.

Comment: Using `exec` with user input... Nothing could go wrong there

Comment: How would I change the web server user to my logged in user? I believe you're right, because my logged in user has different privileges.